# не работает: $dbResult = CUser::GetList("id", "desc", [], []);

Tags: битрикс

помогите исправить неработающий код $dbResult = CUser::GetList("id", "desc", [], []);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод CUser::getList() первые два параметра принимает по ссылке, а константы передавать по ссылке нельзя. Поэтому нужно делать так:

```
$dbResult = CUser::GetList($by="id", $order="desc", [], []);
```

Переменные $by и $order, конечно, можно назвать по-своему.